# C# screen scraper to grab values in sequential order

Tags: c#, asp.net

I load the contents of a webpage into a string. The unique values that I want to extract are like so:

```
>1<    >Goons<
>2<    >Worms<
>3<    >Hampsters<
>4<    >Clouds<
```

The numeric value will always be in order, but the Team name will change day to day...I want to extract the rankings of each team and store them to the database.

So far I wrote a function that will pass in the URL:

```
 protected void HandleURL(string teamsURLFile)
    {
        string searchValue = null; 

        string[] teams = new string[32] { "BirdDogs","Piegons","Ducks","Badgers","Clouds","Ghosts","Clowns","Kitties",
                                          "Socks","Farrets","Lions","Chumps","HillBillys","Goons","Dragons","Hampsters",
                                          "Fish","SeaBirds","Snakes","Mules","Spiders","Goats","Worms","Bafoons",
                                          "Magpies","Donkeys","65ers","Rockts","Rams","Hampsters","Tubbies","Plumpers"};



        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            if (teamsURLFile.Contains(">" + i + "<"))
            {
                foreach (string teamName in teams)
                {

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Any ideas on how I can extract the team name associated with the rank?

Comment: I would recommend to read the rank as well as the teamname directly out of your given website. After reading them out you can store them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
           string val=">" + i + "<";
           int start= teamsURLFile.IndexOf(val);               
           start = s.IndexOf(">",start+val.length);
           int end = s.IndexOf("<",start);
           string team= s.Substring(start, end - start -1);
           //do whatever you want to do with team  

        }
```